# How to prevent flies sticking to hood fan lightbulb guard?

Tags: cleaning

I hope this is not OT. I'm struggling mightily with little flies and other bugs getting stuck all around my hood fan but the worst part is the lightbulb guard. Is there anything that can be done about preventing it? My hood fan (which does vent outside, luckily) is exposed to my oil rich cooking and resulting fumes although I do clean it regularly.

[image]

Comment: Related, and might be of use to you: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46613/how-can-i-keep-flies-out-of-my-kitchen

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful (but not a complete solution) to leave a fly trap (as in explained here: [How can I keep flies out of my kitchen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46613/how-can-i-keep-flies-out-of-my-kitchen/46614#46614)) on your stove when not in use. Use several around your stove when they seem to be bad.