# Is there any way to avoid fruit flies with my fruit on the counter rather than the fridge?

Tags: fruit

I enjoy keeping bowls of fruits out at room temperature in my kitchen.

This has given me quite an annoying abundance of fruit flies in my apartment.

I've brought my fruit in the fridge to avoid this for now, but I was wondering if anyone has any success or tips to leave fruit out without any fruit flies present?

Note: I've tried leaving some apple cider vinegar nearby but that hasn't been successful in trapping them/distracting them.

Comment: Related, possibly helpful: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46613/how-can-i-keep-flies-out-of-my-kitchen/46614#46614

Answer (score 6):

You've described exactly me and my apartment.   I like bowls of fruit on the counter, but I don't like the inevitable fruit flies.  But I actually haven't had a fruit fly problem for about two years now.  **The solution is to simply lay something over the bowl of fruit.**  Make sure it's breathable, or your fruit will ripen *really* fast.  Cheesecloth, a towel, or piece of netting will all work fine.

This works because the fruit flies can't reach the fruit, so they can't use it to feed and reproduce.  That's same reason putting your fruit in the fridge works.

I have noticed that the fruit still ripen more quickly compared to an uncovered bowl.  This can be a benefit or a drawback, depending on your situation.  Also, a bowl with something over isn't as pretty as an open bowl full of fruit.  But given the choice, I prefer good fruit and no pests.

Comment: We do this with our produce scraps and it works great... I would have posted the same answer except we've never used it for whole fruit, only scraps.

Comment: In hot countries they cover the bowl with some net, like a scrap of mosquito net, so you can still see what's in it. Add weights to the edges so it will stay put. You can buy (or make) really pretty ones with beads sewn round the edges.

Comment: You're right @RedSonja, netting will work fine too.  I updated my answer to include more options than just a towel.

Answer (score 2):

We make a fruit fly trap with Apple Cider Vinegar, a glass, and a piece of paper.  Roll the paper into a cone so that it rests on the rim of the glass and allows about 1-2" of space from the bottom.  Tape it to ensure it does not change shape.  Cut the very tip off to allow room for the fruit flies to get into the bottom.  Add a small amount of Apple Cider Vinegar, making sure it does not touch the bottom of the cone.  Works wonders!  Place near your fruit, and the flies will be able to get in, but not out.  Eventually, they end up in the vinegar.  It really works!  We had been inundated by fruit flies with our tomato harvest, and went from dozens to zero in 24 hours or so.

Comment: This works so very well. I was blown away the first time I tried it and captured all of the ~40 or so fruit flies that had been buzzing around my sink.

Answer (score 1):

I live in a tropical country, and exposed fruits in this climate draw fruit flies like moths to a flame. I generally cover them with a cloth napkin. If inadvertently exposed and the pests are sitting on them, and I'm in a particularly devilish mood, I pass an electric mosquito swatter over them. The ensuing pop sounds are music to my ears! :). I wash the fruits thoroughly though before consuming, cos I am imagining the grubs they must have left on them. That said, fruit flies are very clever, you cannot really outwit them. :)

Comment: Some other solutions: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5109847/Why-s-suddenly-plague-tiny-flies-kitchens.html